# Safari 7 get stuck when loading webfont (woff) from cache

Tags: css, caching, safari, webfonts

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with Safari 7 on a webpage using web fonts

The use of the webfont is properly specified in the CSS with correct URL pointing to a `.woff` file hosted in the server that runs the site.

I clear the cache.

I load the home page, everything is fine.

I load a second page, the page doesn't load.

Inspecting the network activity it comes out that Safari has loaded every resource except the webfont;

it is aware the webfont is in cache, doesn't attemp to reload (no request is sent to the server) but is stuck processing that resource (the spinner keeps spinning).

Reloading the (second) page, results in getting the page loaded just fine.

Other browsers behave with no issues.

Is this a bug in Safari or I'm missing something? Is there any workaround?

Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url( '../font/my-font-webfont.eot' );
    src: url( '../font/my-font-webfont.eot?#iefix' ) format( 'embedded-opentype' ),
         url( '../font/my-font-webfont.woff' )       format( 'woff' ),
         url( '../font/my-font-webfont.ttf' )        format( 'truetype' ),
         url( '../font/my-font-webfont.svg#myfont' ) format( 'svg' );
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this only on 1 Safari or are there other Safari 7s that behave so?

Comment: Tried with only 1 Safari on my mac running 10.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues in the past. Probably it's a problem related to the Safari installation on your machine. Try with other Safari 7 installation on different machine and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I will try with other `Safari`s 7 (and 5/6). If it's just mine that have some configuration/cache files broken then I won't consider this an issue any more.

Comment: Right decision! Actually I was going to propose the same. And if my solution isn't proper, let men know and I'll delete it!

Comment: I tried on other 2 machines running Safari 7. No issues at all. Very probably it's the Safari on my machine that has issues. I think you should just edit your answer: "I had similar issues in the past. Probably it's a problem related to the Safari installation on your machine. Try with other Safari 7 installations on different machine and see if the problem persists". I will accept that answer. Thank you.